# Square root of symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a symmetric matrix $A$. How do I compute a matrix $B$ such that $B^tB=A$ where $B^t$ is the transpose of $B$. I cannot figure out if this is at all related to the square root of $A$. How to find $B$ if $B$ is rectangular?

Comment: Are these matrices over what field?

Comment: On reals and $\mathbb C$ there exists a closed form formula in the $n=2$ case; in general one can hope to diagonalize $A$ or use iterative schemes to arrive at the (in general not unique) $B$'s.  By definition (if a such $B$ exists) $A_{ii} = \sum_{k=1}^n B^2_{ki}$.

Comment: Symmetric matrices on real can be diagonalized. On complex, one needs to switch to hermitian matrices.

Also, since the OP asked for the transposed composition, $A$ should be diagonalized by orthogonal/unitary matrices.

Comment: nd any rectangualr matrix B with any number of columns and fixed number of rows(equal to rows and columns of A) can satisfy the above equation? so how to compute B

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for, is essentially a standard exercise in numerical analysis, which is called Cholesky decomposition, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition. But you should have a positive definite symmetric matrix. If not, you should try a $LDL^T$ decomposition, often also called Cholesky decomposition.

Comment: yes i know this method . Matrix A is real and symmetric my question is say B is of size p by n(supose) so A is of size n by n ..if now i calculate square root by above method i will get matrix which is of size n by n ..now how to extract B from it? is it unique B or there may be more than one B matrix which satisfy this equation? B is rectangular say

Comment: nd any rectangualr matrix B with any number of columns and fixed number of rows(equal to rows and columns of A) can satisfy the above equation? so how to compute B if we want B say of some specific number of columns ..is it possible if we know rank of A?

Comment: if $B$ has more columns than your $A$ matrix, you could fill the extra columns with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

If you are over the field $\mathbb{C}$ and your matrix is self-adjoint (which is already imlplied by symmetric), using the spectral theorem you can diagonalize your matrix, i.e. $D:=UAU^{\dagger}$ is diagonal and $U$ a unitary matrix. To calculate $B$ now, simply take the square root of all diagonal entries in the diagonal form of $A$ and simply transform back: $B=U^\dagger\sqrt{D}U$.  Because $A$ is self-adjoint, so is obviously $B$:

$B^\dagger=(U^\dagger\sqrt{D}U)^\dagger=(U^\dagger\sqrt{D^\dagger}U^{\dagger\dagger})=U^\dagger\sqrt{D}U$
 and therefore

$B^\dagger B=BB=U^\dagger \sqrt{D}UU^\dagger \sqrt{D}U=U^\dagger DU=A $

If you are over $\mathbb{R}$, this still works the same (with $^t$ instead of $^\dagger$ and orthogonal matrices instead of unitary) as long as $A$ is positive semi-definite, otherwise you cannot compute the square root of $D$ within $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: yes i know this method . Matrix A is real and symmetric my question is say B is of size p by n(supose) so A is of size n by n ..if now i calculate square root by above method i will get matrix which is of size n by n ..now how to extract B from it? is it unique B or there may be more than one B matrix which satisfy this equation? B is rectangular say

Comment: nd any rectangualr matrix B with any number of columns and fixed number of rows(equal to rows and columns of A) can satisfy the above equation? so how to compute B if we want B say of some specific number of columns ..is it possible if we know rank of A?